# Paypal ipn post not arriving

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I'm having difficulties with Paypal IPN. I have set up a Buy Button that links back to a script (ipn.php inevitably) and to test that it is working, the only code in it is as follows:

```
$from = "Guide Test Page";
$to = "me@btinternet.com";
$subject = "VERIFIED IPN";
$message = "Post: ".serialize($_POST)."<br>";
$headers = "From:" . $from;

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo "Mail Sent";
```

So it sends me an email, hopefully with all the Paypal Post variables. What happens when I go through a 'Buy' is that the redirect to ipn.php works, I see the text 'Mail Sent' on screen and the email arrives. However, **serialise($_POST)** produces **a:0:{}**

Can anyone suggest what is going on?

Comment: always tag the appropriate language you are using

Comment: i think your confusing return url with the ipn, the ipn is hit by a paypal bot not seen by a human, the return url is where  the human buyer comes back to your site

Comment: the ipn sends data thru the url variables so use $_GET not $_POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't think you'd see "Mail Sent" on your screen at all, since the IPN script would be called (independently) by PayPal at some point after you submit the transaction (could be instant, could be a few-many seconds). Are you perhaps using that IPN.PHP as your return URL?

Comment: Thank you - that is exactly what I was doing and I have now corrected it. However I still have a problem. I have now set up a script that should respond properly to an IPN message and have changed the IPN notification URL in the Paypal account accordingly. However, Paypal is still sending the IPN message to the old notification URL (I can tell because of its response). Why would that be? Does Paypal require a few hours/days to update its server when details change?

Comment: Further to that, I have now got Paypal to send to the correct notification url by overriding it in the button code using name="notify_url" as a hidden input and now it appears to be responding correctly - hurrah so far!